# Why do we use a wide-band amplification in order to reproduce a sharp pulse without distortion?

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing, fourier

I was reading some content with regards to the Fourier Transform and the uncertainty principle. In the book I was reading that

> Due to the uncertainty principle, in electronics we use a wide-band amplification in order to reproduce a sharp pulse without distortion.

I do not understand the above sentence, so could someone explain why do we use a wide-band amplification in order to reproduce a sharp pulse without distortion and how is it related to the uncertainty principle of the Fourier Transform?

Answer (score 1):

As the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) page says it:

> Generally speaking, the more concentrated f (x) is, the more spread out its Fourier transform f̂ (ξ) must be. In particular, the scaling property of the Fourier transform may be seen as saying: if we squeeze a function in x, its Fourier transform stretches out in ξ. It is not possible to arbitrarily concentrate both a function and its Fourier transform.
>
> The trade-off between the compaction of a function and its Fourier transform can be formalized in the form of an uncertainty principle by viewing a function and its Fourier transform as conjugate variables with respect to the symplectic form on the time–frequency domain: from the point of view of the linear canonical transformation, the Fourier transform is rotation by 90° in the time–frequency domain, and preserves the symplectic form.

So having a pulse with very sharp transitions means it will have a very large spectrum, thus wasting precious bandwidth (and higher EMI). So, in order to limit the bandwidth of the pulse, while still having a pulse, you simply cut off the higher harmonics, or (lowpass) filter it. Whether it's a raised cosine, Gaussian, or whatever other filter, that's up to the special requirement of the task needed to be performed.

Comment: @user10764803 You still need a pulse to have some bandwidth (depending on requirements), as opposed to a narow bandwidth, thus the term wide-band amplifier. Don't take the name literally, it's meant to suggest that it has a higher than "normal" bandwidth, not that it can transmit DC to light, with spare Herz.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's an intuitive explanation without going into the math/physics:

The uncertainty principle says that you can't simultaneously know the position of a particle and its momentum to better than a fundamental limit of accuracy.

With signals it roughly says that a function and its Fourier transform can't both be "small".

So a brief pulse or sharp edge is going to have a "big" Fourier transform consisting of many harmonics or in the case of an ideal step for example an infinite number of harmonics.

Therefore to reproduce such a signal you have to be able to reproduce all the high frequency harmonics, which requires wide band amplification

[Here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/FourierSeriesSquareWave_800.gif) you can see you need lots of harmonics of the fundamental sine wave to make up a square wave.  As the harmonics get higher you get closer to the ideal waveform:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was taught, by a Bell Labs escapee who then went to Tektronixs and designed one of their scopes, that

**SIGNALS HAPPEN IN TIME, NOT IN FREQUENCY**

If you need to preserve the time_information, you need an circuit with very low delay. Since all nodes have parasitic capacitance that demand stored energy,
the circuit needs minimal stored energy or the time_information becomes blurred.